# Best way to create snapshots on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, backup, snapshot

I would like to learn a bit more about Linux but usually when I build a system and try new stuff I mess up at some point and it sucks to start all over, so I rather not experiment that much :D
"Never touch a working system"

So I was wondering which solution would be the best to have a full backup in case all hell breaks loose.

Comment: What type of "snapshot" are you considering? Some filesystems are able to create snapshots, and to then back up those snapshots on external media (e.g. ZFS), but you don't mention filesystems and you don't mention what a "full backup" would actually mean. It's common to back up one's home directory or maybe only particular directories containing important files, but this does not require "snapshotting" in the filesystem.

Comment: Sorry, this is my lacl of knowledge :)
I have ext4 filesystem and yes my goal would be to backup as much as possible of the existing OS to an external drive.

Comment: I was thinking of using rsync to create a backup of the relevant directories under / OR using btrfs and its snapshot feature.
Which one would you recommend?